# Compare Four Columns and Return Label

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to compare membership rosters which contain 2 columns each for first name and last name. If the names match I want to add conditional formatting and a value in a 5th column. (I'm trying to determine who is a member and who is an external contact.)

I've tried to adapt some formulas found here but no luck.

For example:

If Jon and Doe exists in A & B and C & D on any row as long as Jon and Doe are together in both columns, than I would like to add conditional formatting to Jon and Doe in column A & B and add the word "Member" in a separate column. If Jon Doe only exists in columns A and B, then add the word "External" instead of Member. My example image can explain better.

[image: Link to example image]

I got this close but am not able to adapt it to use labels much less conditional formatting. I'm happy to ditch conditional formatting if it's too complex.

```
=INDEX($N:$N,MATCH(1,(A2=$L:$L)*(B2=$M:$M),1))
```

Comment: Referencing entire columns within such constructions is not at all a good idea. Just one instance of your formula, for example, is being forced to perform more than 2 million calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional Format Formula, applied to `A2:B4` in the sample data

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(1,($A2=$C:$C)*($B2=$D:$D),0)>0,FALSE)
```

Status Formula

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(1,($A2=$C:$C)*($B2=$D:$D),0)>0,"Member",""),"External")
```

<sub>Note the `$`'s anchoring `A` and `B` columns</sub>

[image]

Comment: Referencing entire columns within such constructions is not at all a good idea. Just one instance of each of your formulas, for example, is being forced to perform more than 2 million calculations.

Comment: @jos actually Excel is smarter than that.  Many (but not all) functions handle whole column references efficiently

Comment: Some do, but certainly not the construction you give. If you don't believe me, close all workbooks, open a new workbook and place the formula `=MATCH(1,($A2=$C:$C)*($B2=$D:$D),0)` into cell `H1`. Then copy that formula and paste it to a range of say, 500 cells, e.g. `H1:AA25`, and watch it calculate away. Note that there is nothing in columns `A:D`, so if Excel is so 'smart', why is it taking an age to calculate? Because, unlike some formulas, e.g. `COUNTIFS`, etc., the construction you give does not implictily detect the last-used cell within the ranges passed.

Comment: @chrisneilsen thank you so much! It worked for me now and my list is under 200 names so it saved me hours of work.